# How to open a new pop-up from an existed pop-up?

Tags: javascript, html, css, popup, samsung-smart-tv

I am working on Samsung smart TV application, i created a new screen as a pop-up which showed up when i click on a button... the problem is when i tried to open another screen (as a pop-up too) from the current pop-up... i failed!!

This is my codes, please any advice will help.. thanx

HTML CODE:

```
    <div id= "menu_list"  >
    <div class= "menu" >
        <a href="#openModal"  onkeydown="Main.keyDown();">Welcome</a></div>
    <div id="openModal" class="modalDialog"><div>

    <div id= "menu_list2"  >
    <div class= "hello" >
        <a href="#OPEN"  onkeydown="Main.keyDown();">A</a></div>
    <div id="OPEN" class="hi"><div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS CODE:

```
.hi > div {
width:760px;
position: relative;
padding: 100px 100px 450px 100px;
border-radius: 10px;
background-color: pink;

  }   
 .modalDialog > div {
width:760px;
position: relative;
padding: 100px 100px 450px 100px;
border-radius: 10px;
background: #fff;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
    }
```

JAVA SCRIPT CODE:

```
Main.enableKeys = function()
{
$('.menu').eq(current_selected_index).addClass('selected'); 
$('.menu a').eq(current_selected_index).focus();


};
```

NOTE: the first pop-up work correctly when i click 'welcome' button,, but the second one didn't work when i click 'A' button.. is this kinda relate to java script code... i tried to enable the 'A' button but i cant do that in the same enablekeys function,, the both buttons becomes dis-enable when i do that!!!

Answer (score 0):

related issue as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22709232/trigger-buttons-works-just-once). Use key down event in one place and then in switch (for example) handle keys

example:

JS code:

```
Main.keyDown = function()
{
    var keyCode = event.keyCode;
    alert("Key pressed: " + keyCode);

    switch(keyCode)
    {
        case tvKey.KEY_RETURN:
        case tvKey.KEY_PANEL_RETURN:
            alert("RETURN");
            widgetAPI.sendReturnEvent();
            break;
        case tvKey.KEY_LEFT:
            Main.moveLeft();
            break;
        case tvKey.KEY_RIGHT:
            Main.moveRight();
            break;
        case tvKey.KEY_UP:
            Main.moveUp();
            break;
        case tvKey.KEY_DOWN:
            Main.moveDown();
            break;
        case tvKey.KEY_ENTER:
        case tvKey.KEY_PANEL_ENTER:
            Main.enter();
            break;
        default:
            alert("Unhandled key");
            break;
    }
};

Main.enter = function(){
 if (focusedhtmlobject.hasClass('firstAtag')){ /*do something, open dialog*/ $('#openModal').show();
}
else{
/*etc*/
$('#openModal').hide();
}
};
```

I hope that this piece of code is helpful for you

M.